# Kendo Treeview expand and checkbox not working after new value was passed in from a dropdown list

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, treeview

new to stackoverflow and implementing treeview. I'm having an issue where whenever I select a different value from my dropdown list that would populate my treeview the expand and checkbox is not working anymore. But the first time works.

So I have ajax call that would grab a parameter from a dropdown list to return JSON data to populate my tree. Here's my code. I've been pounding my head for this error and I've also tried some solution in the kendo ui documentation but it just doesn't work. Really need some help. Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
dataB1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["branchList"]));
reloadNewBranch = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["reloadNewBranch"]));
$('#comboNewBranch').kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: dataB2,
    placeholder: "Enter branch name...",
    value: reloadNewBranch
});
//Create TreeView
    function onChange(e) {
        $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
        $('#hiddenPackageArray').val('');
        document.getElementById("textTestpassId").innerHTML = 'At least one(1) template must be selected.';
        $('#treeview').empty();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadOldBranchTemplates", "Home")',
            data: { oldBranchName: $("#comboOldBranch").data("kendoAutoComplete").value() },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            data: result,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    hasChildren: true,
                    children: "Templates"
                }
            }
            });

            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            loadOnDemand: false,
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true
            },
            check: onCheck,
            dataSource: viewModel,
            dataTextField: ["TestPassName", "DisplayName"]
            })

        // gathers IDs of checked nodes
        function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
            for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].checked) {
                    checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].Id);
                    let filtered = checkedNodes.filter(function (listOfId) {
                        return listOfId != null;
                    });
                    $('#hiddenPackageArray').val(filtered);
                }
                if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                    checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
                }
            }
        }
        // show checked node IDs on datasource change
        function onCheck(e) {
            console.log("I'm in onSelect function");
            var checkedNodes = Array();
            var treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
            var message = String();

            checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
            console.log("Checkbox changed :: " + this.text(e.node));

            if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {
                message = checkedNodes.join(" ");
            } else {
                message = "No package(s) are selected.";
                $('#hiddenPackageArray').val('');
            }
            $("#result").html(message);
        }
        $("body").css("cursor", "default");
        })
        .fail(function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#mainDiv').append('<p>Status: ' + textStatus + '</p>');
            $('#mainDiv').append('<p>Error: ' + errorThrown + '</p>');
            $('#mainDiv').append('<p>' + xmlHttpRequest + '</p>');
        });
    };
```

Comment: What happens? Any error or strange UI behaviour? Any piece of code is not being called anymore? We need more details.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, the expand icon won't expand and the checkbox does not work as well when I select another value from the dropdown list.